# Can I combine the creation of an element and adding a new element together in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
var layout = new StackLayout
{
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
    Spacing = 0
};
layout.Children.Add(new HeaderTemplate
{
    Header = Settings.cc.LongText().ToUpper()
});
```

Can these two statements be combined in some way?

Comment: Not possible, you will need an instance before being able to add children. There is no support in C# at this time to do that from the initialization.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis ? `Children` is an `IList<View>`, so yes you can add a comma separated list of children in StackLayout constructor via the initializer shorthand. Now I have no idea what a `HeaderTemplate` custom(?) class is (ListView has one), so assuming it is a View subclass, that would work fine. )

Comment: @SushiHangover my mistake, you are right. As pointed out by Limbani Akashs' answer. That is the way to do it :)

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Totally missed Limbani's answer ;-) Guess I did not scroll down far enough, yes, that is it...

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
var layout = new StackLayout
{
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
    Spacing = 0,
    Children = 
    {
        new HeaderTemplate
        {
            Header = Settings.cc.LongText().ToUpper()
        }
    }
};
```